# asp.net mvc file name with & in url throws file not found exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when i am trying to set a href of anchor tag with ***"&"*** in file name, and clicking on it, the server returns 404 not found exception. my url looks like below:

```
<a href="www.domain.com/a&b.txt"
```

although The file ***"a&b.txt"*** stored at the location, the 404 error occurs, it seems that the ***"&"*** in url understands the qurystring key.

Please help!!!

Comment: build your url using Html.Raw(url action)..search google for correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

You will need to URL Encode the querystring parameter values using the [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) Method